# How do I find all files in a git branch that would change another branch once merged

Tags: git, merge, diff

I am trying to run a code quality tool on all changed files within my companys codebase. The problem is that while all feature branches branch of develop, but develop gets merged back into the feature branch once the feature is finished.

If I compare the git HEAD to the merge base, then I would get a lot of additional noise of what happened in develop until I merged it back in.

If I compare the git HEAD to develop, I would get a lot of additional noise of what happened to develop since I merged develop back in.

Github is great showing what Files changed with every pull request. I would love to have the same files as the output of my commandline query.

Basically I would like to ask git "If I would merge this branch in develop, which files would change in develop"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff --name-status HEAD...the-other-branch`, probably? Careful, it's 3 dots. That will be *close*.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the 3 dots. It seems to do the trick so far! Thank you! :D